# How to return generic class with opaque type

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I return opaque type for generic class?

```
func makeFAQController() -> UIHostingController<some View> {
    let viewModel = FAQViewModel()
    let view = FAQView().environmentObject(viewModel)
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    return controller
}
```

> Error: Cannot convert value of type 'UIHostingController<some View>'
> to type 'UIHostingController<FAQView>' in coercion

```
func makeFAQController() -> UIHostingController<FAQView> {
    let viewModel = FAQViewModel()
    let view = FAQView().environmentObject(viewModel)
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    return controller
}
```

> Cannot convert value of type 'UIHostingController<some View>' to type
> 'UIHostingController<FAQView>' in coercion

I want to avoid type erasure if possible.

Comment: Return just base class `func makeFAQController() -> UIViewController`

Comment: @Asperi Hm, yeah, that works. Is there a way to actually achieve generic opaque return? If no, post this as a answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: .environmentObject(viewModel) makes view a some View. Youy could pass the viewModel to the view its initializer instead of using an environmentObject? That will result in retaining its Type.

Comment: @LloydKeijzer you're right. environmentObject makes it some View. Could you please explain why it's happening?

Comment: Because environmentObject is a ViewModifier on the View type which is generic (some View). Thus any view type can use this modifier resulting in it returning Self which is a some View. You could either write a custom ViewModifier on FAQView which wraps the environmentObject modifier and returns its own Type or pass it in the intializer of FAQView instead.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve environment object if we use init and pass viewModel to it? Cause I got fatal error at launch when trying to set `environmentObject` on init. Or you meant to get rid of this property wrapper at all?

Comment: I meant to get rid of the ViewModifier and pass it using the intializer. Otherwise you need to create a new ViewModifier for FAQView which sets the environmentObject but returns FAQView instead of some View.

Comment: `AnyView` is your friend here. Otherwise make the whole enclosing class of the method `makeFaqController` generic over the type that you'll create after modifying `FaqView`. Otherwise just return a `UIVIewController` form that function as @Asperi has suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return base class (there is nothing more generic then *base* class, probably only meta `NSObject`), so

```
func makeFAQController() -> UIViewController {    // << here !!
    let viewModel = FAQViewModel()
    let view = FAQView().environmentObject(viewModel)
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
    return controller
}
```

Comment: I accept this as an answer, because it's the most simple solution to my problem.
We avoid using `AnyView` type erasure and preserve environment object.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use type-erased `AnyView` here:

```
func makeFAQController() -> UIHostingController<AnyView> {
    let viewModel = FAQViewModel()
    let view = FAQView().environmentObject(viewModel)
    let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: AnyView(view))

    return controller
}
```

Another approach avoiding `AnyView` would be to make the enclosing class of `makeFaqController` method generic and store in it a closure/viewBuilder to use as view to host at creation time:

```
class FAQMaker<U: View> {
    fileprivate let _prepare: (FAQView) -> U
    init(_ prepare: @escaping (FAQView) -> U) {
        self._prepare = prepare
    }
    
    func makeFAQController() -> UIHostingController<U> {
        let prepared = _prapare(FAQView())
        return UIHostingController(rootView: prepared)
    }

}
```

The former approach worked for me fine to wrap SwiftUI views into `UICollectionReusableView`.